# Programatic referencing of literals and object properties

Tags: asp.net

I have advice that this might work for programmatically filling a set of literals from a set of object properties:-

```
For i As Integer = 1 To noOfTexts
  Dim ctl As Literal = DirectCast(FindControl("help" & i), Literal)
  If ctl IsNot Nothing Then
 ctl.Text = pageData.help(i).trim()
 ctl.Visible = True
  End If
Next
```

However, the line: ctl.Text = pageData.help(i).trim() fails because it's not understood that pageData.help(i) should translate to pageData.help1, pageData.help2, etc.

Is there some syntax that would achieve this in VS2010 Asp.net VB?

Answer (score 2):

You can reference properties dynamically using [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science))...

```
 Dim PageDataType As Type = GetType(pageData)
 Dim PropertyName As String = "help" & i
 Dim Property As PropertyInfo = PageDataType.GetProperty(PropertyName)
 Dim PropertyValue As String

 If Property IsNot Nothing
     PropertyValue = Property.GetValue(pageData, Nothing)
 End If
```

Note: [Reflection in .NET is slower than direct access](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/351.aspx), but not enough to make its use impractical